# Class getting bordered instead of its element

Tags: html, css

```css
.Menu {
  background-color: black;
  height: 500px;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  border: none;
}
.Menu h1 {
  color: White;
  border: 5px solid white;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
```

```html
<div class="Menu">
  <h1>Home</h1>
</div>
```

[Here the menu is getting bordered with the header tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqWfo.png)

How do i only Border the First Header tag but not also border the Menu?Why does this happen?

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: The border *is* only around the header tag.  Possibly what you want is just border-bottom on that tag, instead of a full border all the way around?

Comment: I just want to border the "Home" all sides but I dont want it to border the menu in which there is the "Home".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not adding a border around the entire menu, it's functioning as expected.  The `h1` is a block level element, so it will be the width of it's parent container. That is why the border is around the `h1` text, but extends all the way out to the edges.

If you want it just around the word "Home", you could add `display:inline-block` to the `h1` styles, which will wrap the border closely around the `h1`.  Use `padding` if you need it to be slightly higher or wider.

Comment: Ok but is there any way to solve this problem but still keeping it as a block element? just Curious

Comment: You could set a `width` on the `h1` and achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
display: inline-block;
```

to your H1 tag